# How to get the number of visits by page, for pages from a website?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, page

How to get the number of visits by page, for *all* pages from a website?
(I use Google Analytics, and know how to create a report for that, but I only have the 10 first pages).

Comment: May you share the template of the custom report you create?

Comment: It's pageviews per page. Go in dashboard, add widget, click on standard's table, page as dimension and visits and a metric. Simple. But the aim is to have ALL pages' number of visitors, not just the top 10.

Comment: Just change the dropdown to show more than 10 results... ?

Comment: For such a need you may use standard report from Behavior -> Site content -> All pages/Landing Pages.

Comment: @Geoff Jackson - zigojacko There are no such an option in the widget he said about. The maximum is 10 rows.

Comment: Widgets on the dashboard are designed to be small overviews of reports. They include the link to the full report which can show more than 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally try to avoid the GA GUI for reporting whenever possible.  Whatever data you are looking for can easily be gained using the API.  the tool below is a fantastic intro to the API.

http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

For the data that you want, just enter the following into the tool:

- dimensions:  ga:pagePath
- metrics:     ga:visits   (ga:visitors if you want unique visitors)
- max-results: 1000    (in case the 50 by default isnt enough)

Getting used to the API will help you get way more from your data IMO.